# Получить уникальный идентификатор основанный на цепочке функций из стека. Быстро

Tags: windows, стек

Подскажите, как быстро получить все функции стека.

Я задавал вопрос на английском https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415497/very-slow-stack-frames-in-static-library и потом более уточненный https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436622/get-unique-id-based-on-stack-trace-fast, но ответов нет, возможно здесь смогут подсказать.

О проблеме: Я написал профилировщик памяти, который перехватывает вызовы `malloc(); realloc(); free();` и составляет отчет.

Один из отчетов показывает, не только функцию/класс, откуда была вызвана `malloc()`, но и всю цепочку функций из стека.

Для идентификации этих цепочек вызовов, по списку функций строится уникальный идентификатор. По принципу crc.

Для построения идентификатора нужно раскрутить стек и получить все вызовы функций.

Проблема возникла при работе с вызовами из статической библиотеки openssl. И, вероятно будет и с другими библиотеками.

Получить функции в стеке можно следующими вариантами:

1. Вызвать CaptureStackBackTrace(). Но, она выдает не полный список функций. Часто одну, например `CRYPTO_zalloc`, которая и вызывает мой `malloc()`.
2. Использовать StackWalk(), но он слишком медленный. И серьезно замедляет работу программы.
3. Использовать регистр ebp:

> ```
> unsigned long prev;
> unsigned long addr = 1;
> int eframes = 0;
>
> __asm { mov prev, ebp };
>
> while(addr != 0){
>     addr = ((unsigned long *)prev)[1]; 
>     prev = ((unsigned long *)prev)[0]; 
>     stack[eframes] = (void*)addr;
>     eframes ++;
> }
> ```

Однако, после `CRYPTO_zalloc` в prev попадает кривой адрес, например 0x2 и в следующем цикле программа падает.

Как получить всю цепочку вызовов? Кажется, что третий вариант с использованием ebp самый подходящий, однако его требуется исправить. Насколько я сейчас понимаю, происходит переключение на другой стек с относительными адресами.

PS. Мне удалось получить быстрый вариант путем кеширования результата работы `StackWalk()` в массив. Поиск по массиву работает намного быстрее, чем вызов данной функции. Однако, в текущем варианте могли появляться коллизии, отчего это решение выдавало неправильные результаты.